# My HDD keeps waking up from sleep even though there's nothing being accessed

Tags: windows, hard-drive, sleep

I've tried many different suggestions found online such as disabling the prefetch, superfetch. Excluded the HDD from windows defender. Turned off storport with a registry edit. Disabled shadowcopy as well as the VSS service. Lastly I've also turned off indexing and the hard drive cache through device manager. The only clue I have is that the system process PID 4 triggers the HDD awake, I found this info using the Process Monitor from windows. Sometimes it won't occur for hours and other times it happens within 10 mins of the drives going to sleep. I have it set to sleep after 5 mins and it properly spins down after 5 mins of being interrupted awake. I'm on the latest update of Windows 10.

Comment: Because it is not otherwise mentioned, I assume your OS is on a HDD.  Windows Defender cannot entirely be excluded from your OS. Updates are constantly checked. Email may be checking occasionally.  All my production machines are now SSD and activitiy is pretty much meaningless.  If you suspend the machine, then activity should stop. Set updates for off hours when not suspended.

Comment: Yea i should've added that the 2 HDD that keep waking up are not the OS drives. The OS is on a SSD. These 2 HDD's are used mainly for storage and have no programs installed on them.